# UDP сервер и клиент

Tags: golang, udp

Написал тестовый UDP сервер

```
func server() {
    destinationAddress, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "192.168.0.255:8080")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    connection, err := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, destinationAddress)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer connection.Close()

    for {
        connection.Write([]byte("1111"))
    }
}
```

UDP клиент

```
func client() {
    serverAddress, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    connection, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", serverAddress)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer connection.Close()

    for {
        inputBytes := make([]byte, 1024)
        connection.ReadFromUDP(inputBytes)
        fmt.Println(string(inputBytes))
    }
}
```

Получается у меня сервер рассылает broadcast сообщения внутри сети 192.168.0.0, клиенту для получения сообщения необходимо прочесть сообщение со своего порта 8080

Можно ли написать UDP сервер и клиента так, чтоб для получения информации клиентом ему необходимо было подключиться к определенному серверу? Если такое возможно, то приведите пример кода сервера и клиента

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под "подключением" ? Сам протокол UDP подразумевает что подключение не требуется. Клиент зная IP-адрес/порт сервера может послать ему запрос, на что сервер может ответить. Если требуется некое "подключение", то первым запросом от клиента может быть какой либо пакет приветствия, например с логином и паролем или какой нибудь еще, удовлетворяющей дальнейшие потребности "подключения" информацией. После чего север запомнит у себя, что такой то клиент (ip/порт) присылал такой запрос, а следовательно считается подключившимся

Answer (score 0):

Да, это возможно. Для того, чтобы клиент подключался к определенному серверу, необходимо изменить адреса, на которые сервер и клиент будут слушать соединения. В вашем коде сервер рассылает broadcast сообщения на адрес 192.168.0.255:8080, а клиент слушает соединения на адресе :8080. Чтобы клиент подключался к определенному серверу, нужно указать адрес сервера в качестве аргумента для функции DialUDP, которую использует клиент для подключения к серверу. Также сервер должен слушать соединения на определенном адресе, а не на адресе 192.168.0.255:8080.

Вот пример кода сервера и клиента, которые позволяют клиенту подключаться к определенному серверу.

Сервер:

```
func server() {
    serverAddress, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    connection, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", serverAddress)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer connection.Close()

    for {
        inputBytes := make([]byte, 1024)
        _, clientAddress, err := connection.ReadFromUDP(inputBytes)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println("Received message from", clientAddress)
        fmt.Println(string(inputBytes))

        // отправляем сообщение клиенту
        _, err = connection.WriteToUDP([]byte("Hello, client!"), clientAddress)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

Клиент:

```
func client() {
    serverAddress, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "server-address:8080")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    connection, err := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, serverAddress)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer connection.Close()

    for {
        _, err := connection.Write([]byte("Hello, server!"))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }

        inputBytes := make([]byte, 1024)
        _, err = connection.Read(inputBytes)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println(string(inputBytes))
    }
}
```

В этом примере сервер слушает соединения на адресе :8080, а клиент подключается к серверу с адресом server-address:8080. Обратите внимание, что в коде клиента нужно указывать адрес сервера, на который нужно подключаться